# Parse::CSV, parsing file without headers

Tags: perl, csv, parsing

The data I've been given is a dump from a mysql database and some of the files are missing column headers.

When I try to fetch a row, ***say Dumper $parser->fetch;*** returns undefined on the files without column headers.  I've done an if (-e $file) and it sees the file.  I've also tried

**names => 1**

and

**names => ['id', 'description']**

and both times the output was undef, though for the latter $parser->names did output *id* and *description* (the names, not the column values).

Am I assigning the column names correctly?  If so, why is it returning undefined?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use v5.24.3;
use strict;
use warnings;

# Modules
use Data::Dump;                                     # dd \%hash
use Data::Dumper;                                   # say Dumper(\%hash)                        
use Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX;
use Text::CSV_XS;
use Parse::CSV;

my $path    = './path/to/data/';
my $vendor  = 'fwd';
my $ext     = '.csv';
my @f       = (
    'spring_categories',
    'prod_descriptions',
    'feature_bullets',
    'category_mapping'
);
my $file = $path . $vendor . '/' . $f[1] . $ext;

my $parser = Parse::CSV->new(
    "file"        => $file,                                       
    "names"       => ['id', 'description'],
    "csv_attr"    => {
        "sep_char" => ',',
        "quote_char" => "'"
    }
);

# Not triggering error
if ( $parser->errstr )
{
    say "There was an error";
}
else
{
    say $parser->names;             # outputs | iddescription
    say Dumper $parser->fetch;      # outputs | $VAR1 = undef

    # Doesn't reach while
    while ( my $value = $parser->fetch )
    {
        say Dumper $value;
        say $parser->row;

        # my @names = $parser->names;
        # dd \@names;
        # say $names[0];

        die;
    }
```

Here is a temporary test file I made to share without confidential data that has the same issue for me.

```
4732947234,"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"
6732947274,"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo"
7657657274,Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas 
3993007274,magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem
2449049474,"laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur"
4732947273,"laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur"
8732947270,"ntium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa "
```

Comment: @Andrey I cannot share the data im using, but to reproduce just create  a CSV with 2 columns, the first being serial numbers and the second being a short description (I used lorem ipsum).  I created a short 7 row csv file with random 10 digit numbers and lorem ipsum and it is still getting me the same result.

Comment: do you have issues with files missing header or with all the files?

Comment: @Andrey it is just with the files missing headers.  I created a temporary download link for the test csv file I made.   https://expirebox.com/download/eb9bf54d625a5ac6c2832972359b107a.html

Comment: @Andrey I copied that test file and added headers and it still returned undefined.  I also copied the headers and first 7 rows out of a working file and pasted them in and it also didn't work.

Comment: what is the end goal? You just need to parse all rows from CSV files and ...?

Comment: So you have some CSV files that work and some that don't, and now you think it's unrelated to the headers?

Comment: Code is missing a `}` closing curlie bracket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor specifies `quote_char => "'"` whereas your sample data file uses double quotes `"`

If you have no headers in the CSV data then you should use `names => 0` to get the module to return arrays of data instead hashes keyed by column name

I also suggest that you `open` the file explicitly and check that it succeeded. Then you can pass what you know is a valid file handle in the `file` parameter instead of a path string

Comment: The Dumper line inside the error else block now outputs the first row, but it's still not making it into the while loop.

Answer (score -1):

The code below parses the test.csv file you poste:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV_XS;
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 1, sep_char => ',', allow_whitespace => 1, allow_loose_quotes => 1});
open my $fh, "<", 'test.csv' or die "Unable to open test.csv: $!";
while (my $row = $csv->getline ($fh)) {
    foreach my $filed (@$row) {
        print "[$filed]";
    }
    print "\n";
}
close $fh;
```